# React js useState hook. How to update state of a json object with an a array in it when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, handlebars.js, react-hooks

I am sending my state as a  `stringified` variable from a form to a POST request through a lamda server which then parses it and sends it to sendgrid which there I am using send grids templating feature. Which requires me to have json Formatted like this in order to loop over one particular part (multiple checkboxes) which all should have the same key but a different value, set by a `reason="Weight Loss"` in the form. Here is how the eventual json needs to be formed.

```
{
  "name" :"anders",
  "message" : "winfsdafasfdsfsadfsadnipeg",
  "package" : "silver",
  "email" : "email@email.com",
  "subject" : "fdsafas",
  "data":{
      "reasonArray":[
         {
            "reason":"weightLoss"
         },
         {
            "reason":"Sport"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Then I can do some magic and loop over the reason's that were checked in the checkbox

```
<ol>
  {{#each data.reasonArray}}
    <li>{{this.reason}} </li>
  {{/each}}
</ol>
```

Now I had it working if I left the state with single key value pairs and don't have the `data` portion.
Here is what my initial state looked like working.

```
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    package: `${data.datoCmsPricing.title}`,
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    weightLoss:"",
    strength:"",
    sport:"",
    message: "",
  })
```

I then had the following `onChange` event that set the state with the name of the input field as the key and the value or checked state as the value. Seen here

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox' && !e.target.checked) {
        setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked});
    } else {
        setFormState({...formState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }
 }
```

and here is my form

```
<form onSubmit={submitForm}>
      {/* <input type="text" name="package" value={data.datoCmsPricing.title} /> */}
      <label>
        Name
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={formState.name}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Email
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={formState.email}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Subject
        <input
          type="text"
          name="subject"
          value={formState.subject}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <div>
        <h3>Reasons for wanting to train</h3>
        <label>
        Weight Loss
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="weightLoss"
          checked={formState.weightLoss}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>
        <label>
        Strength 
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="strength"
          checked={formState.strength}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>
        <label>
        Sport 
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="sport"
          checked={formState.sport}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>
      </div>

      <label>
        message
        <textarea
          name="message"
          value={formState.message}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I then send it off to my lamdba function

```
  const response = await fetch("/.netlify/functions/sendmail", {
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify(formState),
     })
```

Now my state looks like the following in json after being sent to lamdbda function and being parsed

```
{ 
  name: 'Anders',
  package: 'silver',
  email: 'email@email.com',
  subject: 'fdsafa',
  weightLoss: 'on',
  strength: 'on',
  sport: 'on',
  message: 'fdsafasf'
}
```

Now I want to have my initial state to look like the format that sendgird wants it in, so this is what I attempted with my state setup.

```
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    package: `${data.datoCmsPricing.title}`,
    email: "",
    subject: "",
    weightLoss:"",
    strength:"",
    sport:"",
    message: "",
    data:{
      reasonArray:[
        {
          reason:""
        },
        {
          reason:""
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Then I tried to update the onChange event for the checked values with the following, I also update my form so it grabs a user friendly name for the reason. Seen below this code

```
 const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox' && !e.target.checked) {
        setFormState({...formState, data:{ reasonArray:[ { reason:e.target.reason}, ]}});
    } 
    ...
 }
```

Form Changes

```
  ...
     <label>
        Weight Loss
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="weightLoss"
          reason="weightLoss"
          checked={formState.weightLoss}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>
        <label>
        Strength 
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="strength"
          reason="strength"
          checked={formState.strength}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>
        <label>
        Sport 
        <input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="sport"
          reason="sport"
          checked={formState.sport}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        </label>
   ...
```

The resulting Json I get after the Post request is this, with my attempt. It does not update the data part. So the resulting Json is in the right format, but it doesn't have the reason's attached. Thanks ahead of time for any help.

```
{ 
   "name":"Anders",
   "package":"Silver",
   "email":"email@email.com",
   "subject":"fdsaf",
   "weightLoss":"on",
   "strength":"on",
   "sport":"on",
   "message":"fdsafas",
   "data":{ 
      "reasonArray":[ 
         { 
            "reason":""
         },
         { 
            "reason":""
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Attempting Rabi's answer

```
  ...

 const prepareDataForApi = (formData) => {
  const newFormData = Object.assign({}, formData); // optional if passed cloned copy of formData object or you can also use lodash cloneDeep
  newFormData.data = {
    reasonArray:[]
  };

  Object.keys(newFormData.reasons).forEach(key => {
    if(newFormData.reasons[key]){
      newFormData.data.reasonArray.push({reason: key})
    }
  });

  delete newFormData.reasons;

  return newFormData;
}



 const submitForm = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setForm(false);



  // const newFormData = prepareDataForApi(formData); 
     const newFormData = prepareDataForApi(formState);

  console.log(newFormData);

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Keep your initial state like this :

```
{ 
   "name":"Anders",
   "package":"Silver",
   "email":"email@email.com",
   "subject":"fdsaf",
   "message":"fdsafas",
   "reasons": {
      "weightLoss": true,
      "strength": true,
      "sport": true,
   }
}
```

2. Modify onChange():

```
 const onChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
        const changedReason = e.target.getAttribute('name');
        setFormState({...formState, reasons:{...formState.reasons, [changedReason]: !formState.reasons[changedReason]}});
    } 
    ...
 }
```

3. Change form's `onSubmit()`:

   > Before calling api , call converter function which will convert `formState` to JSON format required by your lambda function

```
const prepareDataForApi = (formData) => {
  const newFormData = Object.assign({}, formData); // optional if passed cloned copy of formData object or you can also use lodash cloneDeep
  newFormData.data = {
    reasonArray:[]
  };

  Object.keys(newFormData.reasons).forEach(key => {
    if(newFormData.reasons[key]){
      newFormData.data.reasonArray.push({reason: key})
    }
  });

  delete newFormData.reasons;

  return newFormData;
}
```

Comment: so do I put the prepareDataForApi function outside or inside my form submit handler? and then I console.log(newFormData) to test?

Comment: Keep it outside of submit handler , just call `prepareDataForApi` inside submit handler, something like this:

`
prepareDataForApi = () => {
   func def ....
}

onSubmit = () => {
    const newFromData = prepareDataForApi(formData);
    console.log(newFromData);
}
`

Comment: The do I console log `newFormData` inside like this `prepareDataForApi = () => {console.log(newFormData);}`?

Comment: You can do that if you want to print the newFromData in browser console.

Comment: yeah i just want to debug it first before I get to the next step. I will try that

Comment: Sure, makes sense.
I have not tested the code but hopefully it should work.

Comment: You have to modify all the checkbox to something like this: 
<input 
          type="checkbox"
          name="weightLoss"
          reason="weightLoss"
          **checked={formState.reasons.weightLoss}**
          onChange={onChange}
        />

Comment: I added my answer above with my attempt, I am missing where to put the `prepareDataForApi = () => {func dev ...}` hopefully you can see my mistake

Comment: Pass **fromState**(this is where you are maintaining the form data) instead of formData(it's not defined anywhere);

**const newFormData = prepareDataForApi(formState); **

Comment: So I'm having one issue, now my checkboxes won't toggle, they just stay set as true?

Comment: Have you modified the onChange() ?

Comment: no I am using your on change. I did a merge so that might be the issue I am going to roll back and just manually test, I'll get back to ya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204446/discussion-between-anders-kitson-and-rabi-jha).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your new `onChange` is not replacing all of your nested values when you update a key. Try this instead:

```js
setFormState({
  ...formState, 
  data:{ 
    ...formState.data, // keep keys from previous data object (not necessary if it only contains the key you are specifying though)
    reasonArray:[ 
      ...formState.data.reasonArray, // keep previous entries from reasonArray
      { reason:e.target.reason}, 
    ]
  }
});
```

An alternative would be to use an `effect`.

```js
const [formState, setFormState] = React.useState({...}):

// Runs every time weightLoss is changed
React.useEffect(() => {
  let newReasonArray 
  if (formState.weightLoss) {
    newReasonArray = [...formState.reasonArray]; // So we dont mutate state
    newReasonArray.push({reason: 'weightLoss'});
  } else {
    // If you want to remove it from the array if its unchecked
    newReasonArray = [...formState.reasonArray];
    newReasonArray.filter((reason) => (reason.reason != 'weightLoss'));
  }

  console.log(newReasonArray) // Test if it is updated correctly

  // Set the state with the new array
  setFormState({...formState, data: { reasonArray: newReasonArray }});
}, [formState.weightLoss]);
```

Comment: hmm, I get a `__proto__: Object` where the `data{Reason...` should go.

Comment: I am getting a reasonArray is not defined, I must have messed up somewhere.

Comment: hmm, I still end up with blank values for the `reason`

Comment: Are you trying to add to the array of reasons? or trying to modify the current values?

Comment: well I would like to do both. I thought I had to have the array in the state to start. But If I could add the array after and change the value of `reason` that would be ideal. If that makes sense. I want Reason to change to a value of `Weight Loss` or `Sport` all depending on what was checked in checkbox. But it needs the spaces in between (depending) so it's more readable in the email in the end

Comment: Can it be multiple reasons?

Comment: like in the json at the very bottom of my question